# Use .htaccess file on an apache localhost server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration, directory, localhost

Alright, I got an Apache localhost server up and running with PHP and MySql. Now I want to be able to use a `.htaccess` file as well to use `RewriteRule`, But I'm at a loss where to put it.

I have these directories:

`C:\dev\progs` where Apache PHP and MySQL are stored, each in their own sub-directories, ie. `C:\dev\progs\Apache` and so on...

`C:\dev\www` where all the site files are stored.

I need to know where to put the `.htaccess` file, what configuration I need to do, and if what I'm my hopes and dreams are all for nothing.

Thanks

Comment: I thought `.htaccess` config should not be used if you have access to the server config file, which in this case, you do.

Comment: yeah, I heard something about that too, I just find the config file a little confusing. I can also find a lot more tutorials on `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.htaccess is a configuration file that should be stored where your page is. In short, it should be in `c:\dev\www` in Your case, but You should read [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) too. BTW don't forget to turn on mod_rewrite by deleting a hash from the line where it resides

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and enable .htaccess by changing

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: confirm that you have enabled the rewrite_module on Apache server and also check your httpd.conf file to make sure that there is no "#" i.e. commented at the beginning of this line 

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 16):

**Enable .htaccess on apache servers in localhost**

```
1) Find your apache directly which uses the php installation .
2) Open your httpd.conf  with notepad, Which is located in the path \apache\conf directory
3) Find the code like below       
      #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
4) Remove # from above code


# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
 # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
 #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
 #
 AllowOverride All   <--- make sure this is not set to "None"


5) Save httpd.conf file
6) Restart your apache server
```

Comment: Thanks. Just adding a small part to avoid Step 1 & 2 for WAMP users. Click on the WAMP icon, scroll to Apache. You will directly get the `httpd.conf` file to edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /projectfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You place `.htaccess` file in the web directory you want the code to control (and any sub directories). For a Rewrite, it typically goes in the root dir and acts upon the index.php page.

For example, if you put the `.htaccess` file in \dev\www\ directory, and your `.htaccess` file has something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` this is a regex that is saying get all the characters in the URL and append them to the `/index.php?` script. The `/$1` is a back reference in regex.