# HTML - Display Multiple Images (possibly with Button)

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, lamp

Alright, so I have created a Portfolio Page for a Model containing several images, but I want to add a bunch more images using a specific HTML script. As a programmer, I try to eliminate redundancy, but I don't know anything about JavaScript or PHP.

**What I want:**

- Iterate over each image file in a directory (./images)
- Loop a specific block of HTML, plugging in the path to image.

***Bonus***

- Execute code when Button is pressed, displaying more images within current window (i.e "Portfolio" button -> Extend.php).

My Site: ChrisNguyen.ml/Portfolio

**Example Code** (Other example in raw HTML in a above link):

```
<?php
$dirname = "images_all";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<article class="4u 12u$(xsmall) work-item">
        <a href="'.$image'" class="image fit thumb"><img src="'.$image'" alt="" /></a>
        <h3> </h3>
    </article> ';
}
?>
```

**HTML Block that needs to be repeated:**

```
    <article class="4u 12u$(xsmall) work-item">
        <a href="images/fulls/01.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/fulls/01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <h3> </h3>
    </article>
```

**Other Info:**
LAMP Server running on AWS EC2 (So I can use PHP, etc)

In case you didn't get it:

1. How do I display multiple images with HTML using a "For loop"?
2. How to display more images with Button.

**Update:**
It does support PHP because of the SMTP form at the bottom of the page.

**Update 2:**
I am implementing all your guy's suggestions (thanks!), and modifying the HTML page and other files, and testing it with the live server/site. I do see changes in the page, but not the results desired (i.e the page displays the variable name rather than the value "{$dirArray[$index]}")

Comment: I don't see a question here. Anyone?

Comment: Obviously your server does not support php execution.

Comment: What exactly do you need?  Does your site not already loop through those images?

Comment: @u_mulder The questions are implied within the context. But I'll clarify that at the bottom for you ;) ...and it does support PHP, did you not look at the actual website? Or the fact it is a LAMP server? xD

Comment: Why then I see php code in your source?

Comment: @LukePark I need a function (PHP or JavaScript) to display multiple images (so that I dont have to keep adding 4 lines of HTML code to display one of the dozens of images.

Comment: @u_mulder That code doesn't work. It is an "example" code of what I want it to look like.

Comment: @ChrisNguyen parts like `href="'.$image'"` should be `href="' . $image . '"` [String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: So, you have a `foreach` loop. Have `echo` that echoes html. What is the problem? I don't understand

Comment: Sooo... The code you posted above doesn't work or..?  What is the relevance of the PHP code above?

Comment: @u_mulder  The code doesn't work. It is an example code of what I want!

Comment: It doesn't work __HOW__? Your pc explodes? You have blank page?

Comment: @u_mulder Look at the site (under all the images). It just echos "' $dirArray[$index] '' ); } } ?>"

Comment: So if in your page you see php code instead of results of it's execution - it means that your php code is __NOT EXECUTED__. How do you store it? In a `.html` file?

Comment: @u_mulder go to ChrisNguyen.ml/Portfolio and hit (Ctrl U). But I tried both. I left one php code inside the HTML block, and the other is a separate PHP file that is executed when the user hits the Button near the bottom. Neither of which seem to work. I think it is the string concatenation mentioned by Mihailo. All though I tried his idea, to no avail.

Comment: @Mihailo Alright, so I tried like a dozen variations and permutations of the string concatenation listed in that link, and modified the PHP block with the HTML and the separate file, to no avail. I tried printing (echo) one of the variables, and it just displays the variable name ("{$dirArray[$index]}") . Thoughts?

Comment: @ChrisNguyen Maybe you didn't start the LAMP server?! I don't use LAMP, so I may be wrong...

Comment: @DanCostinel I added another update above. But yeah, the server, instance, etc are all live, so my edits are immediately implemented into the site, to no avail. though. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer above is correct. However, it did not work/execute in the server currently used (Apache) because the server didn't recognize PHP within the HTML itself. That is why it only worked as a separate file.
[ [How do I add PHP code/file to HTML(.html) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files) ]

What I needed to do:

1. Find the directory where the  "httpd.conf" was located. On my AWS Apache server, it was located at "/etc/httpd/conf"
2. Stop your server temporaily ("sudo service httpd stop")
3. Edit the file ("sudo nano httpd.conf")
4. Append "AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html" to tell Apache/the-server how to properly execute the embedded PHP (I put it in the bottom)
5. Also follow instructions here to ensure the httpd.conf file will accept/execute the above line/code [ [Use .htaccess file on an apache localhost server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490209/use-htaccess-file-on-an-apache-localhost-server) ]
6. Start your server ("sudo service httpd stop")
7. ...and if your PHP is correct and embedded properly, your page will now execute the PHP as normal!

Check my site (ChrisNguyen.ml/Portfolio) for the finished result/code.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question correct (it is only an easy and short code example hope it will help you):

**First Question: 1.) How do I display multiple images with HTML using a "For loop"?**

in this code example, all images from the folder "images" will shown on the website.

```
<?php
$path = "";

$allImages= scandir($path);

foreach ($allImages as $image) { 

        $imageInf= pathinfo($path ."/".$image); 

            echo "
            <article class='4u 12u$(xsmall) work-item'>
            <a href='#' class='image fit thumb'><img src='".$imageInf['dirname']."/".$imageInf['basename']."' alt='' /></a>
            <h3> </h3>
            </article> 
            ";
}
    ?>
```

**Second Question: 2.) How to display more images with a Button**

**Only with PHP:** 
this script will show you one more img on your website (i dont know how many images you need or which specific img you need)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['NAMEOFBUTTON']))
{

                echo "
                <article class='4u 12u$(xsmall) work-item'>
                <a href='#' class='image fit thumb'><img src=' (IMAGE PATH WITH IMAGE NAME) ' alt='' /></a>
                <h3> </h3>
                </article> 
                ";
}

?>
```

OR

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['NAMEOFBUTTON']))
{
      for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
      $var_name = "IMAGENAME".$i;
                    echo "
                    <article class='4u 12u$(xsmall) work-item'>
                    <a href='#' class='image fit thumb'><img src=' (IMAGE PATH WITH $var_name) ' alt='' /></a>
                    <h3> </h3>
                    </article> 
                    ";
       }
}

?>
```

OR

```
if(isset($_POST['NAMEOFBUTTON']))
{
    $path = "";

    $allImages= scandir($path);

    foreach ($allImages as $image) { 

            $imageInf= pathinfo($path ."/".$image); 

                echo "
                <article class='4u 12u$(xsmall) work-item'>
                <a href='#' class='image fit thumb'><img src='".$imageInf['dirname']."/".$imageInf['basename']."' alt='' /></a>
                <h3> </h3>
                </article> 
                ";
}
}



?>
<form method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='NAMEOFBUTTON' />
</form>
```

**OR WITH JQuery;**

HTML:

```
<input type='button' onclick='moreimg();' />
<div id='Show_Images'></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script>
function moreimg(){
   $('#Show_Images').load('IMG.php');
}
</script>
```

PHP:
    You can use in the file "IMG.php" the code from the **First Question**

Comment: I tried your first code block and got an Error. ("PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''" class="image fit thumb"><im' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/Portfolio/Extend.php on line 11
")

Comment: For the second part, I have a bunch of images, like a dozen or so. So a for loop would be ideal so that I don't have to keep manually entering the names each time.

Comment: @ChrisNguyen i updated the code .. the error should be gone

Comment: @chrisNguyen if the files are in a folder you can use the code from the first question. if you want a for loop, i will edit the second question

Comment: Hey, so I tried your code again, added a closing brace, changed the directory path ("$path"), and still no luck. I don't think it's pointing to the right location. It gives me the default null img icon... Maybe it doesn't display the image correctly?

Comment: @ChrisNguyen sorry... i copied the wrong variable .. i update the code sorry for the misstake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128101/discussion-between-neptulon-and-chris-nguyen).

Comment: Alright, so I found the problem. I posted my solution below... Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Now remove the dollar sign from the as `$image` and use as in the below code. It might help you.

```
<?php
$dirname = "images_all";
$images = glob($dir`enter code here`name."*.png");

foreach($images as image) {
    echo '<article class="4u 12u$(xsmall) work-item">
        <a href="'.$image'" class="image fit thumb"><img src="'.$image'" alt="" /></a>
        <h3> </h3>
    </article> ';
}
?>
```